# Compiling QT 5.3.2 under windows 7 and msvc

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt

I'm using msvc 2013 (ultimate-64bit), windows 7 64bit.
I compiled icu4c 54.1 by msvc 2013 (64 bit).

And now i try to compile **qt 5.3.2-everywhere-opensource-src** ( i added patch there (i replaced `QWebFrame.cpp`))

I used CMD developer tool from visual studio.

--- And i executed these commands:

1. `cd D:\qt`
2. `d:`
3. `configure -prefix D:\Qt\Qt_making -platform win32-msvc2013 -opensource -c++11 -make tools -make libs -qt-sql-sqlite -no-openssl -icu -I C:\icu-53.1-vs2013\include -L C:\icu-53.1-vs2013\lib64` // all OK - after all, include loaded/ new icu libs loaded
4. `nmake`

After 4 command the process interrupted. And displayed error:

with: `36 unresolved externals` these 'unresolved externals' is propably about libs.

I make screen of these errors (below):

[image: Errors]

So whats wrong?

I have to compile QT (in particular QWebKit - becouse of the patch all on 64 bit.)

Comment: Hello. Are you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The last time I compiled Qt for Windows (in order to get the desktop version of OpenGL), here's what I needed to do. Note that this was with VS2010 and Qt 5.0.0 (on Windows 7).

```
set CL=/MP

if not compiling qtwebkit:
    Need to rename/delete the qtwebkit* directories (there's a -no-webkit option but it doesn't work in 5.0.0)
else:
    Need ICU, GNU bison, and GNU gperf (either install the prebuilt binaries or build yourself)

if using ICU (required for qtwebkit):
    set LIB=%LIB%;C:\icu\lib
    set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;C:\icu\include
    set PATH=C:\icu\bin;%PATH%

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\gperf\bin;C:\bison\bin
cd <path>\qt-everywhere-opensource-src-<version>
configure -prefix C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0-opengl-desktop -opensource -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2010 -opengl desktop -no-cetest -nomake tests -nomake examples -confirm-license -ltcg -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -mp
nmake
nmake install

if used ICU:
    copy all the DLLs from C:\icu\bin to C:\Qt\Qt5.0.0-opengl-desktop\bin
```

Comment: okey i have compiled QT with your method. All have compiled fine. But there is not 'QtWebKit' i make `nmake module-qtwebkit` and `nmake install` but still there is not qtwebkit. Your method have compiled these [link to img](http://i.imgur.com/9uZv944.jpg)

Comment: @Thomas: Hmm, sorry about that. I'm pretty sure that compiled webkit in back then, but as I mentioned that was a while ago now. (I only put this as an answer because it was too long for a comment.) Perhaps if you try explicitly passing the `-webkit` flag to `configure`? Also, how did you get that screenshot? What are the DLLs in the actual `bin` install directory?

Comment: This screenshot i made from visual studio 2013 in qt project settings. `configure -prefix d:\Qt\Qt5.0.0-opengl-desktop -opensource -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2013 -webkit -no-cetest -nomake tests -nomake examples -confirm-license -ltcg -qt-zlib -qt-pcre -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -mp
`
-webkit 'unknown option'

Comment: @Thomas: Oops, looking back at the documentation I consulted it seems `-webkit`  was only for 4.8. I'm afraid I don't know how to get webkit compiled beyond what I already put in my answer, which you say doesn't work :/ Are you sure the DLL isn't in the `bin` directory of the prefix path?

Comment: Yes - MSVC did not detect webkit too

Comment: @Thomas: Hmm, that's annoying. I poked around a bit -- is it possible that `qtwebkit` has to be downloaded and build separately? There seems to be an entire repository just for it: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebkit/source/946088cf515ec30de586392ec72e4658b86650a4: